# What modern (PCL) equivalent for Handshake.XOnXOff?

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, handshake, portable-applications

I was using this legacy code:

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
```

...but trying to port it to VS 2013 / .NET 4.5.1 in the "Core" (Portable Class Library) portion of a Xamarin solution, I get, "*The name 'Handshake' does not exist in the current context*"

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.handshake%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the Handshake enum is in System.IO.Ports namespace, but adding that to my usings evokes "*The type or namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 
'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*"

Perhaps I *am* missing an assembly reference? The link above says it's in System. My only reference is ".NET Portable Subset" which I *assume* (I know, I know, when you ASSume you Aynchronously Syncopate Sinkholes or something like that) would have System embedded in it.

When I r-click References and select Add Reference..., the options proffered are somewhat slight:

[image]

So...how can I use Handshake.XOnXOff? If I can't, what are my viable options?

Comment: I don't believe that Windows Phone supports Serial IO.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Oh, yeah, this is code (originally for a handheld device) that prints labels on a belt printer. I reckon a phone/tablet would be able to "air print" to a more conventional type of printer...or, perhaps, to retain the functionality, a belt printer could be peripheraled to a phablet or tablet?

Comment: Coincidentally, both relevant disambiguations of PCL come to mind in this scenario (Portable Class Library and Printer Command Language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to implement print functionality in a platform agnostic way.  Your best bet would be to define some sort of IPrinting interface.  That interface can be implemented in a platform specific library, then a reference can be passes into your PCL, so that the PCL can hand off the printing duties via the Interface.

Comment: How would that look? Each device calls a method like PrintLabel(iPhone) or PrintLabel(Android) or PrintLabel(WP8), - etc., perhaps - and then the core code (that would naturally do such underhanded, I mean low-level, things) then calls the device-specific code? Or...???

Comment: Yes, something like that.